# Bottom border CSS Margin

Tags: html, css, border

I am very new to this community and if this question has already been answered then I apologize I couldn't seem to find it on google or here under other questions.

I am trying to make a border for the body of the page that will not leave any space on any of the sides. I used margin to move the border to the edge for top, right and left but the bottom i am having a hard time with.

heres my CSS for the body border

```
body {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background-color: gray;
    border: 10px outset #596779; 
    height: 600px;
    text-align: center;
     }
```

Comment: use `height:100vh` and add `box-sizing:border-box`

Comment: might need to use `html, body {} `

Comment: OMG TY!! that did the trick. i had a simple workaround that i was using but the box-sizing:border-box made fit perfect.